# cv2.imdecode return None when decode base64

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm quite new to python, and i'm creating a function to decode from base64 to image, everything work fine except cv2.imdecode alway return null

Here is my example base64:

```
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
```

And here is my function read base64 :

```
    def readb64(base64):
        nparr = np.fromstring(base64, np.uint8)
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        return img
```

I used Debug and see `nparr` has below value, but `img` alway return None:

```
[105  86  66  79  82 119  48  75  71 103 111  65  65  65  65  78  83  85
 104  69  85 103  65  65  65  70  89  65  65  65  65 101  67  65  89  65
  65  65  67  50  88 101 110  50  65  65  65  65  65  88  78  83  82  48
  73  65 114 115  52  99  54  81  65  65  65  65  82 110  81  85  49  66
  65  65  67 120 106 119 118  56  89  81  85  65  65  65  65  74  99  69
 104  90  99 119  65  65  68 115  77  65]
```

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: are you sure that nparr is a decodable value? the length of nparr is 100 and i think your decoding to a 3 color system. according to https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#cv2.imdecode "If the buffer is too short or contains invalid data, the empty matrix/image is returned."

Comment: So maybe the line `nparr = np.fromstring(base64, np.uint8)` i used is wrong ? or I need to change base64 above to something else ? I have tried many way but it not work :(

Comment: are you sure that the base64 image has three color spaces? perhaps the flag cv2.IMREAD_COLOR is wrong, your data might be just grey scale.

Comment: my image has color but the background is transparent, maybe it is problem ?